# Specifying the coordinate for line margin, not for line center

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I want the marginal point of a line start to be positioned at a certain coordinate, not the center point (which seems to be default). Is there something similar to `\draw[anchor=north] (0,0) -- (1,0);` ?

Here is a snippet from my code. You can see the two extra extended lines wobble at margin points of the stack.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
 rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=center}]
\node[stack=5] (stack) {
    \nodepart{one}$m_1$
    \nodepart{two}$m_2$
    \nodepart{three}$m_3$
    \nodepart{four}$m_4$
    \nodepart{five}$m_5$
};

\draw (stack.north east) to ++(.5cm, 0);
\draw (stack.south east) to ++(.5cm, 0);
\node[at=(stack.five east), right] {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: line wobble]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `outer sep=0pt` in `stack/.style`.

[image: tikz-rect-corner]

See the explanation on Page 219 in the [pgfmanual (Version 3.0.1a)](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

> The default for this option is half the line width. When the default is used and when the background path is draw, the anchors will lie exactly on the “outside border” of the path (not on the path itself).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
 rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt}]
\node[stack=5] (s) {
    \nodepart{one}$m_1$
    \nodepart{two}$m_2$
    \nodepart{three}$m_3$
    \nodepart{four}$m_4$
    \nodepart{five}$m_5$
};

\draw (s.north east) to ++(.5cm, 0);
\draw (s.south east) to ++(.5cm, 0);
\node[at=(s.five east), right] {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```